Unable to locate element when the webpage navigate from one section to another after click on "save and continue" button


<ul>
        <li class="first current"><a class="jump">
                Crop
            </a></li><li class=""><a class="jump">
                Soil
            </a></li><li class=""><a class="jump">
                Inputs
            </a></li><li class=""><a class="jump">
                
                Fuel &amp; Energy
            </a></li><li class=""><a class="jump">
                
                Irrigation
            </a></li><li class=""><a class="jump">
                Carbon
            </a></li><li class="last "><a class="jump">
                Transport
            </a></li></ul>



#!pip install selenium
#!pip install webdriver_manager

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import csv
import time
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import requests
DRIVER_PATH =r"C:\Users\Suman.Sourav\Downloads\chromedriver_win64"
service = Service(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
def driversetup():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #run Selenium in headless mode
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    #overcome limited resource problems
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("lang=en")
    #open Browser in maximized mode
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #disable infobars
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    #options.add_argument('--window-size-1920, 1080')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined});")
    return driver
driver = driversetup()

#Deleting repositories
#Importing crop data csv file
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/sample_data.csv')



#Setting up the google chrome browser for loggin in to cool farm tool
driver.get('https://app.coolfarmtool.org/account/login/')
username = '********'
password = '*********'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id_username"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id_password"]').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login"]/p[3]/input[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="welcome-content"]/section/ul[1]/li[1]').click()
#driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#dialog_metrics > form > label:nth-child(1)').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#dialog_metrics > form > label:nth-child(2)').click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div:nth-child(10) > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > div > button').click()
#driver.refresh()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
#Crop data entry
  #Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_crop_type")).select_by_value("10")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_crop_type")).select_by_value(str(row['crop_name']))
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_reporting_year")).select_by_value(str(row['harvest_year']))
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_field_size_value"]').clear()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_field_size_value"]').send_keys(str(row['crop_area_ha']))
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_field_size_unit")).select_by_value("10")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_product_fresh_value"]').clear()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_product_dry_value"]').clear()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_product_fresh_value"]').send_keys(str(row['harvest_amt_tonnes']))
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_product_fresh_unit")).select_by_value("9")
  time.sleep(2)
  #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_product_dry_value"]').clear()
  #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_product_dry_value"]').send_keys(str(row['farm_gate_amt_tonnes']))
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_product_dry_unit")).select_by_value("9")

  #Planting/sowing date date
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_date_planting_time")).select_by_value("1")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_date_planting_month")).select_by_value("4")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_date_planting_year")).select_by_value("2023")

  #Harvest date
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_date_harvesting_time")).select_by_value("3")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_date_harvesting_month")).select_by_value("7")

  #Assessment name
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_name"]').clear()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_name"]').send_keys(row['farm_id'])
  #driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/crop_view.png")

  #Assessment name should be customised as per the farm details

  #Crop residue management
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_residue_amount_value"]').clear()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_residue_amount_value"]').send_keys(str(row['residue_amt_kg_pr_ha']))
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_residue_amount_unit")).select_by_value("24")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_residue_management")).select_by_value("6")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#controller > ul > li.last > button').click()
  time.sleep(2)
  driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/crop_view.png")

  #driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.container.p-0 > nav > div > ul:nth-child(1) > li.current').click()
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_template")).select_by_value("96227")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_soil_texture")).select_by_value("1")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_soil_type")).select_by_value("2")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_soil_organic_matter")).select_by_value("2")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_soil_moisture_sowing")).select_by_value("2")
  Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_soil_drainage")).select_by_value("2")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_label"]').clear()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_label"]').send_keys(row['farm_id'])
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#controller > ul > li.last > button').click()
  driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/crop_view.png")
  time.sleep(2)
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.container.p-0 > nav > div > ul:nth-child(1) > li.first.current > a').click()

I am filling details on an online tool by looping through each rows of a csv file in Google colab. I can successfully login and fill first section of the form but the element of the next section is not locatable although with the help of screenshot I can see the code takes it to the second section.
I have programmed to loop through each row of the data sheet which contain all section's information of the online tool. I am expecting that each round of loop covers all the section until final result of each row of the data sheet and then start from the first section of the tool. The final results of each row should be scrapped later and get integrated with the original data sheet.
